# SUM with Windows Function BIGQUERY

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to know the number of goals scored away and at home for each team in each season

```
season  |home_goal  |away_goal |team_home |team_away|
-----------------------------------------------------
1       |  1        |0         |France    |Spain    |    
1       |  1        |2         |Italie    |Spain    |     
1       |  0        |1         |Spain     |Italie   |      
1       |  1        |3         |France    |Italie   |     
1       |  1        |4         |Spain     |Portugal |    
1       |  3        |4         |Portugal  |Italie   |    
2       |  1        |2         |France    |Portugal |         
2       |  1        |0         |Spain     |Italie   |     
2       |  0        |1         |Spain     |Portugal |      
2       |  3        |2         |Italie    |Spain    | 
2       |  0        |1         |France    |Portugal |    
...     | ...       |...       |...       |...      |
```

I want this output

```
    season  |hg         |ag        |team      |
    -------------------------------------------
    1       |  2        |0         |France    |   
    1       |  1        |8         |Italie    |    
    1       |  1        |2         |Spain     |      
    1       |  3        |4         |Portugal  |    
    2       |  1        |0         |France    |  
    ...     | ...       |...       |...       |
```

I don't have the expected result, I only have the goals scored at home...

```
 WITH all_match AS (SELECT
    season,
    match.team_home AS ht,
    match.home_goal AS hg
  FROM
    match
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    season,
    match.team_away AS ta,
    match.away_goal AS ag
  FROM
    match)
SELECT
  season,
  ht,
  SUM(hg)
FROM
  all_match
  group by 1,2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below approach

```
select * from (
  select season, 'home' location, team_home as team, home_goal as goal
  from your_table 
  union all
  select season, 'away' location, team_away as team, away_goal as goal
  from your_table 
)
pivot (sum(goal) for location in ('home', 'away'))
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]